# How to upload MultipartFile from external link?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload, multipartform-data, multipart

I already have controller which accepts `MultipartFile`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadImage" )
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(@Validated MultipartFileWrapper file,
        BindingResult result, Principal principal)
```

Was appeared new requirement. We need to load file from external resources(dropbox for example) and resave on local mashine. I know link to load as prerequisite.

I want to reuse first controller. Thus my aim - using external link download file with type MultipartFile and pass it to existing controller.

How does spring suggest to resolve my issue ?

**P.S.**

`MultipartFileWrapper` just wrapper under the `MultipartFile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

```
<!-- Integration-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and following code(I reduced exception handling)

```
    InputStream inputStream =   new URL(url).openStream();  
    File file = File.createTempFile("tmp", ".txt", new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
    byte[] binary = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, binary);
    UploadedMultipartFile multipartFile = new UploadedMultipartFile(file, file.length(), "jpg",
                "formParameter", fileName);
    MultipartFileWrapper multipartFileWrapper = new MultipartFileWrapper();
    multipartFileWrapper.setMultipartFile(multipartFile);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(multipartFileWrapper);
    return "redirect:/member/uploadImage";
```